# How to migrate a Virtual Server from one account to another

Tags: virtual-machine, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, virtual-server

I was wondering how to migrate a Virtual Server from one account to another one.

In particular, if I have a VSI on a Softlayer account and I want to migrate the same to a IBM Cloud account (the new one which includes the IaaS part as well), how can I do that?

Thanks in advance guys,

Answer (score 1):

You can "Share Image With Account Number" from the image description page.
You have to make the image template of the VSI and input your account number at first.
After sharing image, you can deploy your VSI from your shared image template.

or you can utilize the function of export and import the image template between your accounts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know if the ip and all the network configs are gonna changed by moving the vsi from one account to another one?

Comment: The networking components do not get captured as part of the imaging process. When you share the image with another account and they spin up a VSI from that image they will get unique IPs and networking configs.